Is there a difference between V and F in German?
So in the German language, the letters F and V are both present. F is pronounced the same as in English. V however is pronounced the same as [f] whereas the sound it represents in English is usually written as W. My question is, is there any rule as to when to use V and to use F because they both sound the same to me?

Check the pronunciation of Vater, Vase, variabel and von and for fun also Phase. Also compare English cough, rough, enough, though, dough, through

Yes, there is a difference. F is always pronounced the same in German (i.e. as [f]) which is identical to the English pronunciation. (German Fisch and English fish are both pronounced identically as [fɪʃ].) But the letter V is sometimes pronounced as if it was an F (»vier« is pronounced as [fiːɐ̯]) and sometimes as if it was a W (»Vase« is [ˈvaːzə], and »Wasser« is [ˈvasɐ].) (German W is pronounced like English V: German: »Wien« = [viːn]; English »Vienna« = [viˈɛ.nə])
(For IPA-Symbols used as notation for pronunciation see: International Phonetic Alphabet on English Wikipedia or Liste der IPA-Zeichen on German Wikipedia)
Here is why:
The letters v and V are graphemic variants of f and F since Middle High German (MHG). MHG was spoken in the southern half of the German-speaking area between 1050 and 1350. It is the predecessor of the New High German language, and thus of modern German. Therefore, v and V are pronounced like f and F in all German heritage words.

Viele Väter vermissen vier verrückte Vögel.
[ˈfiːlə ˈfɛːtɐ fɛɐ̯ˈmɪsn̩ fiːɐ̯ fɛɐ̯ˈʁʏktə ˈføːɡl̩]

But the vocabulary of the German language contains not only inherited words but also many loanwords that have been added to the German vocabulary from foreign languages. And (almost) all words that contain a V and were imported (mainly from the French language) after the 14th century are pronounced as if a W were written instead of the V:

Virus, Vampir, Vase, violett, vegetarisch, Klavier, Pullover, oval
[ˈviːʁʊs vamˈpiːɐ̯ ˈvaːzə vioˈlɛt veɡeˈtaːʁɪʃ klaˈviːɐ̯ pʊˈloːvɐ oˈvaːl]

So: the usual pronunciation of the letter V is the same as the letter F, but there are also many loanwords in which the V is pronounced like a W.
Note, that there are also some exceptions and special cases:

Advent

Standard pronunciation: [atˈvɛnt]
also allowed in Austria and Switzerland: [atˈfɛnt]


Nerv, nervös etc.

Nerv: [nɛʁf] (as if it was written "Nerf")
Nerven: [ˈnɛʁfn̩] (as if it was written "Nerfn")
nervig: in northern regions: [ˈnɛʁfɪç], in southern regions: [ˈnɛʁfɪk] (as if it was written "nerfig")
but:
nervös: [nɛʁˈvøːs] (as if it was written "nerwös" although it is directly derived from Nerv)




Q: How do I know which pronunciation is correct?
A: Do it the same way like German native speakers did when they were children: Learn the pronunciation of each word separately.
If you have to guess: The pronunciation like German F ([f]) is more common than that of German W ([v]), so use the F-sound as your first choice, except for words that doesn't look German but French or Latin. Then the W-Sound ([v]) is the better guess.
German inherited words have one or two syllables. If they have two syllables, then the first syllable is stressed and the last syllable very often contains the letter e. Use this as a rule of thumb and note, that there are man exceptions (like »Vase« which fits these rules, but still is a loanword imported from French).

Strictly speaking this doesn't answer the question.

Just to be clear, when you say it's pronounced like W, you mean a German W, so like an English V. German spelling rules to have their quirks and exceptions, but by comparison English spelling rules are complete anarchy. @Carsten S - I think the rule here is that if it's native word then V sounds like English F, otherwise it sounds like English V. But that's not a big help if you don't know where the word comes from.

@RDBury, the question is when to just v and when to use f for the f pronunciation.

Not to forget Karl Valentin, who insisted to have his name pronounced "Falentin", because "man sagt ja auch nicht 'Water' und 'Wogel'.

The question is: when is the sound [f] written as <v>, when as <f>.
The first thing to note is that <v> is only used stem-initially. This alone should be sufficient to consider <f> the default and <v> the exception.
The number of stems that have <v> is relatively small and easy to memorise.

von, vor
viel
voll
vier
ver- (prefix)
Vater, Volk, Vogel, Vogt, Vetter

These stems appear in numerous compounds (which aren't always semantically transparent, which makes recognising them as compounds harder).

vor+aus, vor+her, vor+hin, vor+über
da+von, wo+von, hier+von
viel+leicht
Ver+ein, Ver+lag, Ver+trag, Ver+kehr

So there is no rule as such, but it is no wonder that misspelling <v> as <f> and vice versa is relatively rare, as <v> appears exclusively in initial position in a low number of high-frequency stems.
